# How to perform QA when dev provided no deliverables?

Tags: automated-testing, agile-testing, eclipse

The development team will release new epic after 30 days, today is day 1 and they did not provide any deliverables.

What should a QA Engineer do to assure high quality?

Comment: I removed "Question 1-For a case study where we automate Gmail Login functionality using WebDriver in Eclipse, what would be the **Health Check Test cases**?" - one question per questions please.  It is fundamental to how the site works

Comment: I removed "need generous and detailed help. I would appreciate if the responses are quick".  That is a universal need on this site for everyone asking a question.  We are also looking for questions and answers that will apply to others in a similar situation.  This is not a free consultancy services to solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

When testing objectives are unclear (and often even if they are) I go to our generally accepted standards:

Have cases for the following types of tests and tag them accordingly

- Smoke - basic page loads
- Happy - perfect user, functions work
- Sad - user makes mistakes
- Compliance - audit/legal requirements
- Optional - non-required workflow

I also look at the test cases based on the test pyramid and the Agile Testing Quadrants and I look at what we have for unit and integrated tests and what should be added for UAT testing in the UI.

I also have to learn the business domain and cases so I know what's appropriate and useful to check for the business cases that should be tested